# How to connect to elasticsearch localhost from google colab windows machine?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, google-colaboratory

I have my localhost for elasticsearch running, accessing through python

In my google colab i have installed 'pip install elasticsearch'
If i access es, i get coneection refused

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
message_body = {"size":1000, "_source": index_columns, "query":{"match_all":{}}}
elastic_data = es.search(index=data_index, body=message_body, scroll='1m')
```

below connection error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I tried

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}],timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)
```

Still i get connection refused

Comment: Have you tried ngrok?
Can anyone confirm if google colab can access local PC resources and services?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a google-colab project runs on a server from google which can not access your local machine directly.

I did connect my Dockercontainer running a elasticsearch instance on my localhost to google colab with the help of ngrok. Through ngrok you can create a url under which your elasticsearch cluster that runs on your localhost is publicly available (a so called tunnel). I followed [this tutorial](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/).

**First you need to install ngrok.**

For MacOS, use HomeBrew:

```
brew install ngrok/ngrok/ngrok
```

For Linux, use Apt:

```
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null && \
  echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list && \
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install ngrok
```

For Windows, use Chocolatey:

```
choco install ngrok
```

**Then setup ngrok with your Authentification Token**

For this you need to sign-up [here](https://ngrok.com) for a ngrok account. There you will obtain a Authentification Token. Then run the following command

```
ngrok config add-authtoken TOKEN
```

and  replace "TOKEN" with your actual token.

**Now you can start ngrok by running the following command.**

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER
```

Replace "PORTNUMBER" with the port of your localhost you want to connect  to.

Now you should see something like this in your terminal:

```
Session Status                online
Account                       inconshreveable (Plan: Free)
Version                       3.0.0
Region                        United States (us)
Latency                       78ms
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    https://84c5df439d74.ngrok-free.dev -> http://localhost:8000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Now you can use the url provided under 'forwarding' to connect to your localhost.

**Since the whole world can access this URL, we need to secure it quickly.**

Stop your ngrok process (crtl + c) and run:

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER --basic-auth 'username:password'
```

**Now you can use this URL in google colab to connect to localhost**

In my  google-colab project I connected the a docker container running elasticsearch like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{
        'host': 'c04c-89-128-141-226.ngrok-free.app',
        'port': 443,
        'scheme': 'https',
    }],
    basic_auth=('username', 'password')
)
```